# Prometheus metrics are not accessible in Grafana, when VM is having two IP's (public and private)

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I had setup Prometheus, node-exporter and Grafana in same VM. The VM is having two IP's (internal & External). I'm able to access Prometheus metrics and able to launch Grafana through external IP.  But Prometheus metrics are not showing in Grafana dashboard. But i am able to access other external IP prometheus metrics in grafan.

Any configuration changes required?

Answer (score 0):

The Grafana frontend (JS app running in your browser) issues API calls directly to Prometheus, so you can use your browser's developer tools to see where those requests are being sent to and what happens with them.

If you're running Chrome, right click anywhere in Grafana, select *Inspect* and then the *Network* tab.

Else, you can do it directly from Grafana. In the panel editor there is a *Query Inspector* button somewhere, which shows you the request and response, although I'm not sure about HTTP status codes and such.